# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1083cfea8)

Tags: ios, swift

When I added the `paperOnboarding` pod, build and run my swift program. After it succeeded, my app crashed and threads appeared. Asking for help to fix this problem. Thank you so much.

[image]

**Thread 1: ViewController.viewDidload**

```
 //titleArray = ["picture 1","picture 2","picture 3","picture 4","picture 5","picture 6","picture 7","picture 8","picture 9","picture 10","picture 11"]
    carouselView.delegate = self
    carouselView.setCarouselData(paths: pathArray,  describedTitle: titleArray, isAutoScroll: true, timer: 3.0, defaultImage: "defaultImage")
    //optional method
    carouselView.setCarouselOpaque(layer: true, describedTitle: false, pageIndicator: true)
    carouselView.setCarouselLayout(displayStyle: 2, pageIndicatorPositon: 2, pageIndicatorColor: UIColor.gray, describedTitleColor: nil, layerColor: nil)
}
```

**Thread 1: 34 UIApplication Main**

```
  0x109aa4057 <+159>: movq   0x115b602(%rip), %rbx     ; (void *)0x0000000108319d00: objc_release
```

**Thread 1: 35 main**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

**Thread 1:36 main**

```
  0x10e822955 <+1>: movl   %eax, %edi
```

**ViewDidload**

```
 @IBOutlet weak var carouselView: AACarousel!

var titleArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let pathArray = [
                    //array of images here               

    ]


   carouselView.delegate = self
   carouselView.setCarouselData(paths: pathArray,  describedTitle: titleArray, isAutoScroll: true, timer: 3.0, defaultImage: "defaultImage")
   // optional method
   carouselView.setCarouselOpaque(layer: true, describedTitle: false, pageIndicator: true)
   carouselView.setCarouselLayout(displayStyle: 2, pageIndicatorPositon: 2, pageIndicatorColor: UIColor.gray, describedTitleColor: nil, layerColor: nil)
}

func startAutoScroll() {
    //optional method
    carouselView.startScrollImageView()

}

func stopAutoScroll() {
    //optional method
    carouselView.stopScrollImageView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

Here's the initial part of my 'AppDelegate.swift' file 'KingFisher' is the only code I added.

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher
```

Comment: Instead of posting screenshot, post code.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the code

Comment: @pchocoios have you initialize the carouselView?

Comment: yes, I initialized it.

Comment: Show error message in console.

Comment: I tried to put comment in my carouselView code,  threads disappeared and my app run smoothly but the problem now is my carouselview is not showing because it's in comment area. how can i show again my carouselview and paperonboard without showing threads.

Comment: Set the Exception Breakpoint to get more detailed information

Comment: How can i set the Exception Breakpoint?. Sorry, it's my first time encounter this. Thank you

Comment: Show us entire `viewDidLoad` or any other parts of code where `carouselView` is initialised. This crash happens because when you user `carouselView` it has already been deallocated...

Comment: I already included the 'viewDidLoad'in my attached source code.. Kindly check if I did something wrong or something missing, the reason why my app crashes. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ladislav Thank you for giving time to response on my concern, I already included my 'viewDidLoad' and 'AppDelegate.swift'. Is there something missing or wrong code execution? Thank you for your help.

Comment: before `carouselView.delegate = self` do `print(carouselView)` and see if something gets logged in the console or if it now crashes in `print` line

Answer (score 0):

Go to storyBoard and select your view carouselView and set "AACarousel" to this for class.